# How to suppress composer autoload when installed as an unused dependecy?

Tags: 7, javascript, composer

I'm running a D7 site with the composer module installed as an unused dependency of the OpenLayers Module. The issue I'm having is that my watch dog log is filled with `RuntimeException: Autoloader not found: /var/www/html/phisigmarho.org/sites/all/vendor/autoload.php in composer_manager_register_autoloader() (line 173 of /var/www/html/phisigmarho.org/sites/all/modules/composer_manager/composer_manager.module).` and has caused at least one  `/home/phislub9/public_html/error_log [24-Feb-2017 09:57:30 America/New_York] PHP Fatal error: Class ‘SensioLabs\Security\SecurityChecker’ not found in /home/phislub9/public_html/sites/all/modules/composer_manager/composer_manager_sa/composer_manager_sa.module on line 83`

Part of my issue is that the site is on a shared server that I don't think I can install composer on, so I'm kind of stuck letting the errors build up. I didn't think it was a problem till hitting the fatal error, and it's bad practice to let the script run and take up server resources. So is there some way to work around this? I don't use composer for anything, so I would happily get rid of it but it's a dependency. Can a dependent unused module be suppressed in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt composer manager is an unused dependency. It would make very little sense to list that module as a dependency and not using it. Are you sure there are no packages listed on `yoursite.com/admin/config/system/composer-manager`?

It is very likely that the module that defines the dependency requires some composer packages to function properly. Even if you managed to suppress the composer manager module, the main module would not have access to the package that composer was supposed to fetch, and likely will not work as expected. In that case you should consider two things:

1. Move to a host that gives you more privileges
2. Download the site to your own computer, install and run composer in the file directory configured on `/admin/config/system/composer-manager/settings` and re-upload the entire site, including the vendor directory.

If there are really really really no packages, you could try to change composer manager's `status` in the database `system` table to `0`. That disabled the module without checking for dependencies. It could however break a lot of other things, so have your backups and proceed with caution.